# Unity3D GUI.Label is not displayed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to make "Welcome!" string and a button appear on screen by using the GUI Label and GUILayout Button, but it does not appear and there are not any errors that I know of. Unity emulator is ok, but the "Welcome!" string is not displayed in android.
Here is my code, can someone please tell me my problem and if I might have forgotten to do something.

```c#
public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GUISkin Skin;
    public Texture btnTexture;

    public void Awake() { }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        if (this.Skin != null)
        {
            GUI.skin = this.Skin;

        }

        GUI.skin.button.fontSize = 30;

        Rect content = new Rect(30, 100, Screen.width-60, Screen.height-200);

        GUILayout.BeginArea(content);

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        GUIStyle TextStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.label);
        TextStyle.fontSize = 50;

        // Load and set Font
        Font myFont = (Font)Resources.Load("font/stingray", typeof(Font));
        GUI.skin.font = myFont;

        // Set color for selected and unselected
        TextStyle.normal.textColor = Color.yellow;
        TextStyle.hover.textColor = Color.yellow;

        // Display and set the style in string
        GUI.Label(new Rect(50,50,300,70), "Welcome!", TextStyle);

        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();


        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Join", GUILayout.Width(300), GUILayout.Height(80)))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("SingleMenu");
        }
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }

    void Start () { }

    void Update () { }
}
```

Comment: Did you attach the script to a gameobject?

Comment: sure, I've attached the script file. but the string is not displayed. Btw if user come back from next scene to current scene, the string is displayed. In first booting string is not displayed.

Comment: Stop using OnGui and use [the new UI system](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui) instead

Comment: Thanks, but I have to make the string without Unity UI Text component.

Comment: as @Draco18s says .. OnGui is quite out-of-time.
Why can't you use Unity UI ?

Comment: because I have to display strings and list box using several fonts in next step.